# Change SPECIFIC word (and all occurrences) color

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Using WebStorm:
I'm wondering how to select a specific word (like veryImpotantVariableName) and change only it's color and any subsequent usages of the word. So, I could make it a crazy bright color that's easy to see for debugging/checking. Then I could change it back to normal and rinse and repeat for another word/function/etc.

I DON'T mean "highlight matching selected texts" or "Identifier under carat". That's always what comes up in my search for this. Those can be useful but aren't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you not change the highlighted text color for the duration of your debugging session?

Comment: Not for just a specific word and it stays that way. You can highlight a word and then go through your code WHILE its highlighted but I want it to stay a specific color regardless of where my cursor is

Comment: You can make a search in current file (ordinary "Find") and it will highlight all matches as long as Find bar is open and has that text in Find field. if you need this in more than one file -- repeat it in them as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature, please vote for [IDEABKL-6107](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6107) to be notified on any progress with it

Comment: I knew I couldnt be the only one. It would make some things easier. Gave you an upvote